# Where can I find logs of my Compute Engine startup script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a startup script I believe is failing, but where can I find the logs for it? It doesnt seem to appear in StackDriver. My startup script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
whoami

sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536
ulimit -n 65536
ulimit -u 4096

docker run -d --name sonarqube \
  -p 80:9000 \
  -e sonar.jdbc.username=xxx \
  -e sonar.jdbc.password=xxx \
  -e sonar.jdbc.url=xxx \
  sonarqube:latest
```

Comment: Did you install Stackdriver on this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Compute Engine starts up, you will find the logs for the startup in the serial log.  You can read about the serial log here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console